# "&" Malfunctioning in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, cut

I started with PWK and I am stuck at a bash script session.The following code works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in $(cat wordlist.txt); do
host $url.megacorpone.com &
done
```

What this does as told in the lecture is the use of "&" symbol, i.e. the background scanning while one instance has been created and it works correctly.

**But,** when I try the command line:

```
for url in $(cat wordlist.txt); do host $var.megacorpone.com &;done;
```

it gives me a junk output, then shows : `0xarjun@localhost:` and when I press enter, shows the result of previous command. What in the world is happening?

Comment: You are iterating over `$url` and using `$var` inside?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bash man page:

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.

Remove the sequential operator `;` right after the background operator `&`, as both are not allowed together in bash.